# Jibri records audio only, without video

Tags: linux, record, jitsi-meet

I have jitsi and jibri installed on the same server,

everything is working great,

the recording catch only (audio) without video

this is the Chrome settings:

"--headless",
"--ignore-certificate-errors",
"--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
"--start-maximized",
"--kiosk",
"--enabled",
"--enable-logging",
"--disable-infobars",
"--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
"--disable-setuid-sandbox"

I successfully generate MP4 file, but black screen with audio

Update:
All what I have after recording done is MP4 video file with:

- fixed background (earth and penguins around it with black sky full of stars), No real video
- sound (good and clear audio)

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just find the problem,

just remove "--headless" to solve the missing video problem

Command line: nano /etc/jitsi/jibri/jibri.conf

remove "--headless" then save,

then run: systemctl restart nginx jitsi-videobridge2 prosody jicofo jibri

problem solved

thanks